# How to set a emgu imagebox size to a percentage of screen size

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have two side by side Emgu imagebox and I want their size to be relative to that of the users screen size (33% of the screens width). I tried to set it using something like this in the main form:

```
rectangle screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
int screenHeight = (screen.Height/2);
int screenWidth = screenHeight;
```

and then setting the size to these in the designer form but that just led it to not load the imagebox at all. If anyone knows how to do it with a pictureBox, that may work too.

Here is a picture of my form to help get an idea of what I am trying to achieve. I would like to have these proportions on a screen of any size. Like the % feature in css.

http://oi59.tinypic.com/dwdf12.jpg (I have linked it due to lack of reputation)

Comment: Why do you have two images? Sorry, but I don't understand what you need.

Comment: One is for the original image and the other is for the processed image. What i want is for each of those to take up 33% of the screen regardless of what size the user's screen is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tableLayoutPannel and set its columns to 33%. Then just select full on the dock property to fill each cell.